# Newbie: Include "shared" module components in app.module and app.component.html as layout elements

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a "shared" module with 3 components. I want to include these components in app.component.html. How do I do it. So I have in app.component.html:

```
<header></header>
    
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="bg-trick"></div>
  
  <main-nav></main-nav>

  <div class="main-view widened">

    <h1>Here comes my <router-outlet> tag later!</h1>

  </div>
  
  <sidebar></sidebar>

</div>
```

So all of these tags - `<header>`, `<main-nav>` and `<sidebar>` I've declared as selectors in shared module components. In shared.module.ts I added those components in declarations and exports. In app.module.ts I added the shared module file via import and added the into imports SharedModule. Here are my files:

**shared.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { MainNavComponent } from './main-nav/main-nav.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
   ],
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    MainNavComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    MainNavComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
   
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**that's one of my components**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})

export class SidebarComponent {
  
}
```

So my app doesn't work, if I remove the component selector tags from app.component.html it runs correctly. What am I doing wrong? How could components from another module be inserted into app.model and be used as layout components, which are displayed on every page?

Comment: Add the `SharedModule` to the imports of your `AppModule`

Comment: So i had right. I had SharedModlue in the imports, apperently i copied the wrong code here. It displays Loading... in browser, because i added in index.html <app-root>Loading...</app-root>. Any more suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

in app.module.ts you maybe forget to import sharedmodule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```